# Erro ao compilar Allegro

Tags: c++, allegro

Eu instalei e criei o projeto allegro seguindo esse [tutorial](http://www.seucurso.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=143:instalando-a-allegro-no-dev-c-windows&catid=917:c-c-c&Itemid=76).

Estou com esse codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>

int main(void)
{
al_init();
al_show_native_message_box( /* fill in params */ );

return 0;
}
```

e da esse erro:

```
[Error] allegro5/allegro.h: No such file or directory
```

Como corrigir ??

Comment: A Allegro que você instalou foi a versão 4.2, e o código que você está tentando compilar é para a Allegro 5, e mesmo assim, não compila por conter erros. Tente compilar esse código: http://pastebin.com/3gRrafSU Caso não consiga, tente instalar a Allegro no Codeblocks como no vídeo a seguir: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOfmSpU71QA